# Function with curly braces?

Tags: coffeescript

This CoffeeScript code:

```
root = document.getElementById "hello"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    root.innerHTML = "goodbye"
}, false)
```

Gives an `error: unexpected =`. When I compile this code:

```
root = document.getElementById "hello"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", =>
    root.innerHTML = "goodbye"
, false)
```

It works. However, I really don't like the ambiguity of omitting curly braces.

Is there a way to surround CoffeeScript code blocks with curly braces or equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly braces (`{}`) cannot be used for code blocks in coffeescript. Instead you use indentation.

In Coffeescript, curly braces are used in [string interpolation](https://coffeescript.org/#strings) and (optionally) for [defining objects](https://coffeescript.org/#objects-and-arrays).

From [coffeescript.org](https://coffeescript.org/#language) :

> Instead of using curly braces { } to surround blocks of code in functions, if-statements, switch, and try/catch, use indentation.

---

In your example the curly braces are interpreted as an object definition, where an `=` raises an exception as it expects `:` to define object properties.

Indentation to define code blocks is a core feature of Coffeescript. Personally, I don't see this code as ambiguous at all. But in the case of the function not being the final argument, it is very odd to read with the trailing `, false`.

I would suggest splitting out the function definition from the event listener:

```
onDOMContentLoaded =>
  root.innerHTML = "goodbye"

document.addEventListener "DOMContentLoaded", onDOMContentLoaded, false
```

If you really want something to delimit the function, you can wrap it in parenthesis. You will need to include the `=>` within the parenthesis though:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ( =>
  root.innerHTML = "goodbye"
), false)
```